# Best Laravel Scaffolding Crud Generator?

Tags: laravel, crud, scaffolding

Adding crud forms manually is very painful for me. Is laravel a good way to do this?

Comment: You better ask google, not SO. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I feel the pain too. So we made one. **[`composer require goodyweb/jetstream-crud dev-master`](https://packagist.org/packages/goodyweb/jetstream-crud)**. This is a convenient solution especially if you are using **Jetstream**, **Livewire**, and **Tailwind CSS**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voyager is a really powerful Admin backend panel and working with BREAD on Entities is very easy. Give it a try. Could be working better than a standalone generateor.

Answer (score 3):

That kind of question should be done in Google.

But for the sake of being helpful, here it is:

First of all, the use package A instead of a package B depends of the user. For me the best one is [Voyager](https://voyager.devdojo.com/).

Said that, [here you have a nice list of CRUD Generators](https://laravel-news.com/13-laravel-admin-panel-generators).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to give [Laravel-Code-Generator](https://github.com/CrestApps/laravel-code-generator) a shot. It is very advance and very flexable. The great thing here is that you can create resource exiting database or for a brand new database. It also allow you to create a complete API and API-documentation with customization stubs.

[Here is a link to the documentation](https://www.crestapps.com/laravel-code-generator/docs/2.2)